# Materialize Preloader

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm new to web designing and I found MaterializeCSS framework (same purpose as Bootstrap).

So I found the pre-loaders code but unfortunately I don't know where to place it exactly.

I want this circular loader appear when the carousel is loading. This is my Carousel code:

```
<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
```

Where I'm supposed to put the pre-loader code ?

```
<div class="preloader-wrapper active">
<div class="spinner-layer spinner-red-only">
  <div class="circle-clipper left">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div><div class="gap-patch">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the Preloader Code link:
http://materializecss.com/preloader.html

the Carousel Code link:
http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Thanks and I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: I assume you want the preloader to show while the images load and then disappear? In that case you place your preloader above your carousel (you could use absolute positioning inside a relatively positioned wrapper and `z-index`), handle image loading with javascript and when all images are loaded, you remove the `preloader-wrapper` element from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery makes this easy:
https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Make the images invisible with `display:none` in CSS, then use the JQuery loader to load your images:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book">

$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

and if your images are loaded, you set the images visible with Javascript.

For example:

```
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  $('#book').css('display', 'block');
});
```